# match a pattern and print nth line if condition matches

Tags: shell, awk

My requirement is something like this:

```
Read File:
If ( line contains /String1/)
{
  Increment cursor by 10 lines;
  If (line contains /String2/ )
  {   print line; }
}
```

so far I have got:

```
awk '/String1/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+10]}; NR in nr' file1.log
```

Result of this should input to:

```
awk 'match ($0 , /String2/) {print $0}' file1.log
```

How can I achieve it? Is there a better way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close; you need to set the value of the array element.

```
awk '/String1/ { linematch[NR+10]=1; } /String2/ && NR in linematch;' file1.log
```

Each time a line matches `String1`, you save the record (line) number plus 10. Any time you match `String2`, check if the current line number is one we are expecting, and if so, print the line.

Comment: match() is a function, don't try to use that name for an array or other variable.

Comment: That didnt work :(
 syntax error The source line is 1.
 The error context is
                /String1/ { >>>  match[ <<<
 awk: The statement cannot be correctly parsed.
 The source line is 1.

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton; I did not edit this answer very well before posting.

Comment: looks like we both ended up in about the same place - one looking forward, the other looking back. Wonder if that says anything about personalities :-).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to describe your algorithm. Instead of:

```
If ( line contains /String1/)
{
  Increment cursor by 10 lines;
  If (line contains /String2/ )
  {   print line; }
}
```

which would require jumping ahead in your input stream somehow, think of it as:

```
If ( line contains /String2/)
{
  If (line 10 lines previously contained /String1/ )
  {   print line; }
}
```

which just requires you to re-visit what you already read in:

```
awk '/String1/{f[NR]} /String2/ && (NR-10) in f' file
```

Comment: Thank you for the expalination.